# font-awesome and site conversion from older version to latest

Tags: css, angularjs, font-awesome

I am trying to convert our project to use the latest macadmine theme. It was using font awesome 3 and now with switching to font awesome 4 I have to change all icons to the proper names. I found this page https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4 but I don't understand what should I use for icon-1x. In many of the i tags I see two icons defined the second being icon-1x. What should I change it to?

Comment: Could you please include an example of your version 3 tags in order to include the translation to version 4?

Comment: Here is in the code:    time: "fa fa-clock-o icon-1x",
                            date: "fa fa-calendar icon-1x", I converted the first, but don't know how to convert the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icon-1x does not exist in font awesome, even in version 3. Unless you have styles for it included in something else, you can just get rid of it.